# instanceof or method_exist which one should use?

Tags: php, function, class-design, instanceof

In my validation class I am passing different class objects and need to call a method on those class. Now the questions is. How can I ensure that method exists.

Should I use `instanceof` like this:

```
...
...
if($passedObject instanceof MyExpectedClass) {
   //then call the rquired method
}
...
...
```

or should go for `method_exists` like this:

```
...
...
if(method_exists($passedObject, 'MyExpectedMethod')) {
   //then call the rquired method
}
...
...
```

I am confused. Which one is better approach.

### **EDIT**

I know that if passed Object is an instance of the expected class then the expected method will also exist because MyExpected Class implements my interface which contains expected method. Hope this will give more clarity on the scenario.

Comment: your edit doesn't change any answers

Comment: @Alex So what you suggest? I should use method_exist or both? can you please give your opinion?

Comment: I already did that @Ali answer is correct you should use `method_exists`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ashish Awasthi

I know this is an old question, BUT, I wanted to throw my 2pence in...

If you are using OOP, then the correct answer (IMHO) is instanceof, **NOT** method_exists.

method_exists will only return a boolean value, telling you whether the method is defined or not. But instanceof guarantees that the method will exist **AND** that the definition of the method will be in the expected format, eg: it will exist, and that the method expects 2 params (or 3, or however many you have defined for your method). And, if you have used type hinting then instanceof will also ensure that the format of the params (and return values) will be as expected. method_exists cannot do any of that!

Comment: I appreciate the reply but can you add some kind of example for more clarity. Thanks in advance

Comment: indeed, method_exists doesn't tell you anything about the object, and giving it a string instead of object will even try autoloader. see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79623

Answer (score 2):

You can make an interface:

```
interface ExpectedMethodInterface
{
    /**
     * My expected method
     *
     * @return ...expected return type...
     */
    public function myExpectedMethod();
}
```

Then each class that will have this method should implement the interface like this:

```
class MyClassWithExpectedMethod implements ExpectedMethodInterface
{
    /**
     * My expected method
     *
     * @return ...expected return type...
     */
    public function myExpectedMethod()
    {
        ...body for method...
    }
}
```

Then you can check:

```
if($passedObject instanceof ExpectedMethodInterface) 
{
    ... call your method...
}
```

If you use `php` 5.4.0 or higher you can also make a trait and use this inside your class to prevent code duplication:

```
trait ExpectedMethodTrait
{
    /**
     * My expected method
     *
     * @return ...expected return type...
     */
    public function myExpectedMethod()
    {
        ...body for method...
    }
}
```

And then use your trait like this:

```
class MyClassWithExpectedMethod implements ExpectedMethodInterface
{
    use ExpectedMethodTrait;
}
```

Comment: @Witt Please refer my Edit in my question you will see that the Classes Already implementing interafce so checking instanceof is enough. But I want to know which one is better and efficient approach. Thanks for you Asnwer

Comment: Check for the interface. If it has the interface it **must** have the method. That is the whole idea of an interface. `method_exists` will turn every huge class upside down to check for the method while `instanceof` interface only needs to check one thing. Would be interesting to do a batch test. But my gut (expecting comments on this) says checking for `instanceof` interface should be much more efficient.

Comment: This will of course only work if you consistently use the interface in all classes that you want to call the method in... But that is a matter of proper architecture. I found a performance test [here](http://www.matthimatiker.de/2008/10/instanceof-vs-method_exists/). It is in German though. `instanceof` wins with slight advantage, but keep in mind that the class he checks in the test is not vert big.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the most efficient approach, then `instanceOf` is better, but not by much.

```
interface HasMethod {
    public function myMethod();
}

class MyClass1 implements HasMethod {
    public function myMethod() {}
}

class MyClass2 {
    public function myMethod() {}
}

$myClass1 = new MyClass1();
$myClass2 = new MyClass2();

$times = [0,0,0];
$j = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < 100000; ++$i) {
    $start = microtime(1);
    ($myClass1 instanceof HasMethod) && $j++;
    $times[0] += microtime(1) - $start;

    $start = microtime(1);
    (method_exists($myClass1, 'myMethod')) && $j++;
    $times[1] += microtime(1) - $start;

    $start = microtime(1);
    (method_exists($myClass2, 'myMethod')) && $j++;
    $times[2] += microtime(1) - $start;
}

print_r($times);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0.46121835708618 //instanceOf with interface
    [1] => 0.53055930137634 //method_exists with interface
    [2] => 0.4961085319519  //method_exists without interface
)
```

Bear in mind that `method_exists` may cache the result against the specific class called - the Reflection class only inspects a given class once, regardless of how many instances of Reflection you create - this is a performance thing, as class instances won't change definition at runtime, so there's no point in Reflection duplicating effort that will have the same result. I don't know if this applies in this case, but it should, as the same rules apply.

The above example will obviously not apply if you are repeatedly calling `instanceof` or `method_exists` over many different objects - but I would suggest that you focus on code simplicity, readability, and deduplication of effort, because the example shown here shows that there is negligible difference in processing time for each option.

**Not Exists**

Just as an afterthought, I ran the same checks again, this time looking for a method that doesn't exist, and an interface that isn't implemented, and the results were pretty much the same as before.

Answer (score 1):

These are two different validations, instanceof checks whether the supplied object is an instance of a specific class, while method_exists checks if a certain method exists in a class, so the first validation will never tell you if the passed object contains that method, it will only tell you that it's an instance of that method. You should use method_exists()

Simple tests

```
class MyClass {
   public function myMethod() {
       // code
   }
}
$obj = new MyClass;
var_dump(method_exists($obj, 'myMethod')); // true
```

Comment: If I check that the object is of certain class then I know that method exists in that class.  I just wanted to know the better approach. They both can be used in my case.

Comment: It's a weird validation method. but I'll provide an example of what you're saying.. Suppose I was going to a store and I wanted to check if I have money.. would I try to remember the last time I was paid and assume that I still have the money or just straight-out check my wallet to see if I actually have money?

Comment: You can even use `try  catch` but it doesn't mean that it is a good practice and good idea. @Ali answer is correct and you should use `method_exists`. Your argument that if you know the class name you know that it has the method required, equal to you know everything about your code. So if you know everything about your code, you don't need to check the class of variable! You must just know it! ;-)

Comment: Also, you could always use both `if(($obj instanceof MyClass) && method_exists($obj, 'MyMethod'))`

Comment: Please consider my edit on the question, and read the edit part, then please give your opinion.

Comment: @Alex I don't want to use try-catch in my validation.

Comment: @Alex you can't use try-catch in this case, as accessing a method that doesnt exist throws a fatal uncatchable error.